# Android 2.2 App on Zoom1?

Tags: android, arm, zooming

We are developing an application for android 2.2.We do not have a developer phone.Can we load android 2.2 image on Zoom 1 Arm platform?

Thanks,
Dheepak

Answer (score 1):

I found a number of links that suggested that Android would work on the Zoom. Most information seems centered around http://omapzoom.org/, although I also found a [mailing list post](https://gforge.ti.com/gf/project/omapandroid/mailman/?action=ListThreads&mailman_id=22&_forum_action=ForumMessageBrowse&thread_id=1120) from someone who was able to successfully boot the device with Android, but was having media file playback issues.

Based on the cost of development boards, as well as the time it would take to build and load Android on them, I personally think it would make more sense and take less time to simply purchase a phone.

Answer (score 0):

if its just for a final round of testing you can check websites like DeviceAnywhere .They offer you realtime testing on various devices on a trial account for free.